# json to object and object to json

Tags: json, f#

In context of this tutorial on F# snippets http://www.fssnip.net/1l/title/Convert-an-object-to-json-and-json-to-object

Let's say a Person type

```
type Person = {
    entityName: string; 
    entityType: string; 
}
```

and the code to call the web service and convert into json.

```
let internal json<'t> (myObj:'t) =   
    use ms = new MemoryStream() 
    (new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<'t>)).WriteObject(ms, myObj) 
    Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray()) 

let internal unjson<'t> (jsonString:string)  : 't =  
    use ms = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(jsonString)) 
    let obj = (new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<'t>)).ReadObject(ms) 
    obj :?> 't

let requestToken (): Token =        
    let url = "http://example.com"

    let request = WebRequest.Create(url) :?> HttpWebRequest
    request.Method <- "POST"
    request.Accept <- "application/json;charset=UTF-8"

    let response = request.GetResponse() :?> HttpWebResponse
    use reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

    let body = reader.ReadToEnd()
    Console.WriteLine body // result OK
    let result = unjson<Person> body
```

**JSON**

```
{
    "entityName": "john doe",
    "entityType": "client"
}
```

**Error**

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: The data contract type 'Person' cannot be deserialized because the required data members 'entityName@, entityType@' were not found.

1. if someone can add an example on how to call 'json' function passing `result` object to convert the object back into the JSON string
2. Is the Person `type` required to have all fields as per JSON schema or can I choose to leave out non-required fields?

Comment: @Tuomas Hietanen

Comment: why don't you just use [newtonsoft's json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) serializer?

Comment: I've used but trying out this example

Comment: You might need to add the `[<CLIMutable>]` attribute to your record to adorn it with a default parameterless constructor (migtht not be necessary anymore..). But the thing@ is coming from adding the member names, try adding `[<field: DataMember(Name="entityName") >]`  and `[<field: DataMember(Name="entityType") >]` over each record property. Or just use newtonsoft....

Comment: `error FS0039: The type 'DataMember' is not defined.` is there an import?

Comment: correction, it's `[<field: DataMemberAttribute(Name="entityName") >]`

Comment: yes, you need to `open System.Runtime.Serialization`. In F#, you don'T need to add the Attribute suffix. Let me post an example.

Comment: Great, Can you please execute at your end to ensure it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will serialize your record to JSON using the DataContractSerializer. You need to add some attributes for this to work.

```
#r "System.Runtime.Serialization" 
open System.IO
open System.Runtime.Serialization.Json
open System.Runtime.Serialization

[<DataContract>]
[<CLIMutable>]
type Person = {
    [<DataMember(Name="Name") >]
    entityName: string 
    [<DataMember(Name="Type") >]
    entityType: string 
}

let person = {entityName = "ENTITY"; entityType ="TYPE"}


let  toJson<'t> (myObj:'t) =   
    let fs = new FileStream(@"C:\tmp\test.json",FileMode.Create)
    (new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<'t>)).WriteObject(fs,myObj)

toJson<Person> person
```

And this is the output I get in the `test.json` file:

> {"Name":"ENTITY","Type":"TYPE"}

Comment: please add the contents of your test.json file

Comment: I've got it working, [<DataContract>] and [<field: DataMember was key, CLIMutable didn't change a thing, what CLIMutable is for?

Comment: Yes, you might not need `CLIMutable`, it adds a default constructor to your record. The Json file contents are in the Answer in the last line...

Comment: awesome. I owe you coffee, are you available for consulting

Comment: I was also wondering if you know any site like this https://app.quicktype.io for F#, they don't have json to record translation

Comment: what will be the use of default constructor generally speaking?

Comment: [CLIMutable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/core.climutableattribute-class-%5Bfsharp%5D) It's for better interop with .NET, in case something needs to create/change the records. Basically it will look more like a class, but will still be immutable from F#.

Comment: I need more help please, can you please have a look at this other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49292079/http-request-ending-as-bad-request